# mysql-Trigger which update a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns.

```
create table if not exists T(
         Data Varchar(60) NULL ,
          Ora Varchar(50) NULL,
            Fulldate Datetime
);
```

I have many rows but let's select the first row.

```
Data        Ora     FullDate
12062016    013103  Null
```

I want to write a function with the correct data in mysql.

Here is the function:

```
Delimiter $
CREATE FUNCTION Format_data_function(Data Text,Ora  Text)
    RETURNS DATETIME
    Deterministic

BEGIN

RETURN CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(Data, '%d%m%Y'),' ',STR_TO_DATE(Ora, '%H%i%s'));

END $
Delimiter ;
```

I want to use this function in a trigger, here is what i tried:

```
Delimiter $
CREATE trigger project before update
    on t
    for each row

BEGIN


    Update T set Fulldate = Format_data_function(Data,Ora);



End $
Delimiter ;
```

I don't have any error but when I run the following query:

```
select * from T
```

my fullDate is null.I think my problem is with trigger. What is wrong?

Comment: The trigger runs when you update a record. Did you update any records before running the select? Pls not your trigger would update all records every time it runs. You should restrict it to the current record that is being updated. Also, a generated column may be better than a trigger.

Comment: I thought that if i do this trigger with update, i will do this concat for every row. Maybe i didn't understant triggers very well. How can i solve this problem and update the table with fulldate?

Comment: Triggers are not allowed to update the same table that the trigger is attached to.

Comment: i imported Data and Ora from a file, and that works and after i created a column Fulldate which is null, and i want to be completed by trigger.
After trigger i wrote 
set global local_infile = 1;
     LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/fisier.txt'
INTO TABLE T
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 lines
(Data,Ora);
And i have this error

Can't update table 't' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. How can i do that?

Comment: I solved this without update, just put set new.fulldate = Format_data_function(new.Data,new.Ora);
Thanks for helping